# Does the mean of ROI, annualized = the mean of annualized ROI?

Tags: statistics, finance

I'm not sure if I have a math error, or a comprehension error.

I have a series of ROIs over different periods (`30 days`, `5 years`, etc)

```
roi = (value-cost)/cost
```

I also annualized all of these ROIs using this formula:

```
aroi = (value/cost)**(365/days) - 1
```

These return identical values for a period of `365` days as expected.

Now, here is where I get confused. I will use a period of `2 years` as example.

If I take my mean of ROIs over this two year period, I get `23.6%` which annualizes to `11.17%`.

But if I take these same ROI's, annualize all of them, and take the mean of that, I get `10.32%`.

Do I have a math error? Do we expect these numbers to be the same? And if not, which is the better estimate?

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between a large group of mice and a group of large mice - while they'd both make an excellent horror movie, the plot lines would probably be considerably different. So, yes, order definitely has an impact.

In general, the answer is (and I know mathematicians will *hate* this) "it depends" :-). You cannot *rely* on the same results if you change the order of operations.

I'm *tempted* to say it's because of commutativity but, from memory, that applies to a single operation with the *quantities* swapped. So, multiplication is commutative and division is not:

```
10 x 5 = 50,    5 x 10 =  50,    commutative.
10 / 5 =  2,    5 / 10 = 0.5,    non-commutative.
```

Whether that term can apply to the order of mutiple *operations,* I couldn't say for sure<sup>(a)</sup>, but it *seems* related.

In fact, there are a great many operations which produce different results depending on the order. For example, the sum of the square roots of `49` and `64` is `7 + 8` or `15`, whereas the square root of the sum of `49` and `64` (`113`) is about `10.6`.

There are also operations that produce the *same* results, such as "half of the sum" and "sum of the halves".

But your particular set of operations appears to fall in the "different results" category.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> And, since this site is full of math geeks just *waiting* to pummel me if I make a fundamental mistake like that, I'm not going to risk it :-)

Comment: +1 for the first sentence (at least) !